# Retrieve HTM FORM Data from data using react with next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, form-data

I have a use case in which the source site is posting the below mentioned form data to the second web site where i want to display in the second website which is implemented in the react and next js.

Thank you for your assistance, as I am new to the react framework.

```
<form action='www.mysite.com/test' method="post">
<input type='Hidden' name='SecureID' value='240127915991'/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Do you mean by API implementation?

Comment: @MahdiSamavi in react which is my second site i want to print SecureID values

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access POST data in the browser. POST requests are meant to be sent to the server.

From what I understand, you need to send data from A to B and display those values in B. If you don't have any server/API included in this, the only way to accomplish this is to send data using a GET request.

With GET, you will see the value in the URL as `?SecureID=SecureIDValue`. Then you can use `useNavigate()` or `new URLSearchParams()` to get the value and display it.

Comment: In NextJS, you can use `getServerSideProps` to use POST variables on the page. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75441395/1481519 by craigw

Answer (score 0):

Before your POST Request sends the data to `www.mysite.com/test` you could use the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) Hook from react to save the input after every change.

```js
const Component = () => {
  
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <form action='www.mysite.com/test' method="POST">
        <input type='hidden' name='SecureID' value='240127915991'/>
        <input type='text' name='text-field' defaultValue={formValue} placeholder='enter something' onChange={() => setFormValue(event.target.value)}/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You are able to access the value at any time by using `formValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial reading POST body in getserversideprops

https://dev.to/smeijer/handling-post-requests-in-next-js-getserversideprops-50ia